# Inflate TwoWayView in Fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment

I want to inflate `TwowayView` into Fragment.

This is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_game, container, false);
    ArrayAdapter<String> aItems = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    TwoWayView lv = (TwoWayView) view.findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
    lv.setAdapter(aItems);
    return view;
}
```

My fragment_game.xml:

```
<org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
    android:id="@+id/lvItems"
    style="@style/TwoWayView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Can you post more details about the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved
Add:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
```

to Gradle dependencies